# PHP - alternative to Base64 with shorter results?

Tags: php

I'm currently using base64 to encode a short string and decode it later, and wonder if a better (shorter) alternative is possible.

```
$string = '/path/to/img/image.jpg';
$convertedString = base64_encode($string);  

// New session, new user
$convertedString = 'L3BhdGgvdG8vaW1nL2ltYWdlLmpwZw=='; 
$originalString = base64_decode('L3BhdGgvdG8vaW1nL2ltYWdlLmpwZw==');

// Can $convertedString be shorter by any means ?
```

Requirements :

- Shorter result possible
- Must be reversible any time in a different session (therefore unique)
- No security needed (anyone can guess it)
- Any kind of characters that can be used in a URL (except slashes)
- Can be an external lib

Goal :

Get a clean unique id from a path file that is not the path file and can be used in a URL, without using a database.

I've searched and read a lot, looks like it doesn't exist but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: what's your endgame?

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding in the first place?

Comment: you can compress string and then encode it with b64, but that probably won't change anything in case of short string

Comment: @DanielA.White edited, thanks.

Comment: @SzymonD Base64 is not mandatory.

Comment: Just count from 1 to x and use thoose numbers?  Then they are all unique.  If you want the id's associated with an file path without the user being able to find the file path from the id, then use an database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you're using these in a URL, why not use `rawurlencode($string)` and `rawurldecode($encodedString)`?

If you can reserve one character like `-` (i.e., ensure that `-` never appears in your file names), you can do even better by doing `rawurlencode(str_replace('/', '-', $string))` and `str_replace('-', '/', rawurldecode($encodedString))`.  Depending on the file names you pick, this will create IDs that are the same length as the original filename. (This won't work if your file names have multi-byte characters in them; you will need to use some `mb_*` functions for that case.)

You could try using compression functions, but for strings as short as file paths, compression usually makes the output larger than the input.

Ultimately, unless you are willing to use a database, disallow certain file names, or you know something about what kinds of file names will come up, the best you can hope for is IDs that are as short or almost as short as the original file names.  Otherwise, this would be a universal compression function, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything reliable out there that would significantly shorten the encoded string and keep it URL friendly.

e.g. if you use something like

```
$test = gzcompress(base64_encode($parameter), 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE);
echo $test;
```

it would generate characters that are not URL-friendly and any post-transformation would be just a risky mess.

However, you can easily transform text to get URL-friendly parameters.

I use the following code to generate URL-friendly parameters:

```
$encodedParameter = urlencode(base64_encode($parameter));
```

And the following code to decode it:

```
$parameter = base64_decode(urldecode($encodedParameter));
```

As an alternative solution, you could use generated tokens to map known files using some database.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this [Base122 alternative](https://github.com/kevinAlbs/Base122) written in Javascript, but it may be a hint.